# Is there a shortcut to deriving U and V when doing SVD on a diagonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

More specifically, `A = USV^{t}` where A is a square positive definite matrix with all non-diagonal entries equal to 0. In this case, S (matrix of singular values) is just the sorted diagonal values of A; U and V are made up of 1 and -1, but I can't seem to figure out if there's a quick way to figure out which entries of U and V are 1 vs 0.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that in general, SVD is not unique.  However, a way to find *one possible* $U,V$ for your matrix is as follows:

Let $d_1,d_2,\dots,d_n$ denote the diagonal entries of $A$.  Suppose that the singular values are $d_{i_1},d_{i_2},\dots,d_{i_n}$ where $\{i_1,\dots,i_n\}$ is a rearrangement of $1, \dots, n$.  Let $e_1,\dots,e_n$ denote the columns of the identity matrix (the standard basis).  It suffices to take $U = V$ where the $k$ column of $U$ is $e_{i_k}$.

For example, with 
$$
A = \pmatrix{1\\&4\\&&2}
$$
take
$$
U = V = \pmatrix{0&0&1\\1&0&0\\0&1&0}
$$